# Using Proof of Authority (similar to kovan and rinkeby testnet) in my private ethereum network

Tags: testnets, ropsten

Can one run a private proof of authority ethereum network? Similar to the kovan and rinkeby testnet.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's possible.

Check this blog post for how it's done with geth.
https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8

For parity, see https://wiki.parity.io/Proof-of-Authority-Chains.html and for demonstration of how to run a chain yourself, refer [Demo POA Tutorial](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/Demo-PoA-tutorial.md)